# Will the ODBC installed with SAP ASE Trial continue working after ASE trial license expires?

Tags: license-recommendation

I need to know that if I installed a SAP ASE on windows 10 (only choosing the ODBC component to install) with a trial license. Would I still be able to use it (ODBC) after the trial expires?

I used SAP ASE installation to install only the ODBC for windows 10. My intention was to use the ODBC for python as I couldn't make any other driver to work properly.

Also, can I find a similar open-source driver for Sybase using python?

Comment: If it will continue working, or just stop, is anybody's guess. But once the trial period is over, you are not allowed to use it.